# Replace something to an expression

Tags: replacement

After some calculations, I get some long expressions. I want to change some variables to get simple looks.

For a just small example:

[image]

**But it doesn't work.**

I convert the expression to `RawInputForm` in order to ask here. So, it partially works:
[image]

**CODES:**

```
 expr=(2*Sqrt[5]*E^(I*(q*y + (5*x*(a - Sqrt[a^2 + 6*a]))/(3*\[Alpha]*y) + (7*x*(a - Sqrt[a^2 + 6*a]))/(3*\[Alpha]*t)))*Sqrt[\[Alpha]]*\[Delta])/(Sqrt[\[Beta] + 1]*(\[Eta]/E^(\[Delta]*(x + y)) + 4*(E^(\[Delta]*x))^2))
```

Transforms:

```
transforms = {(2*Sqrt[5]*Sqrt[\[Alpha]]*\[Delta])/Sqrt[\[Beta] + 1] -> Subscript[C, 1], (x*(a - Sqrt[a^2 + 6*a]))/(3*\[Alpha]) -> Subscript[C, 2]}






 expr/.transforms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacements acts on the full form of an expression. Look e.g. at:

[image]

[image]

And the expression in your replacement is:

```
(x*(a - Sqrt[a^2 + 6*a]))/(\[Alpha]) // FullForm
```

[image]

You see that `Rational[7, 3]` and `Power[t,-1]` are the reason that the 2 expressions do not match. you may at most match the term in brackets.

Further, the whole expression reads Times[...] and the first replacement changes some terms in Times[...]. MMA then thinks it is done with everything inside Times[...]. Therefore, to make the second replacement, you need to apply ReplaceAll again or simpler, use ReplaceRepeated (//.):

```
transforms = {(2*Sqrt[5]*Sqrt[\[Alpha]]*\[Delta])/Sqrt[\[Beta] + 1] ->
    Subscript[C, 1], (x*(a - Sqrt[a^2 + 6*a])) -> Subscript[C, 2]}

expr //. transforms  // Simplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Slightly change your second rule:

```
rules = {(2 Sqrt[5] Sqrt[α] δ)/Sqrt[1 + β] -> Subscript[C, 1], 
  a - Sqrt[6 a + a^2] -> 3 α Subscript[C, 2] / x}
```

[image]

2. Apply the replacement rules sequentially using [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html):

```
Fold[ReplaceAll, expr, rules]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `ReplaceRepeated` as in Daniel Huber's answer:

```
expr //. rules
```

> ```
> same result
> ```

**Note:** [`ReplaceAll >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = (2*Sqrt[5]*
     E^(I*(q*
           y + (5*x*(a - Sqrt[a^2 + 6*a]))/(3*α*y) + (7*
             x*(a - Sqrt[a^2 + 6*a]))/(3*α*t)))*
     Sqrt[α]*δ)/(Sqrt[β + 
       1]*(η/E^(δ*(x + y)) + 4*(E^(δ*x))^2));

transforms = {(2*Sqrt[5]*Sqrt[α]*δ)/Sqrt[β + 1] -> 
    Subscript[C, 1], (x*(a - Sqrt[a^2 + 6*a]))/(3*α) -> 
    Subscript[C, 2]};
```

The simpler the LHS of a rule, the easier it is to apply.

```
rule1 = Solve[(Equal @@ transforms[[1]]) /. (Sqrt[α] -> sqrt), 
    sqrt][[1]] /. sqrt -> Sqrt[α]

(* {Sqrt[α] -> (Sqrt[1 + β] Subscript[C, 1])/(2 Sqrt[5] δ)} )*

rule2 = Solve[(Equal @@ transforms[[2]]) /. (Sqrt[a^2 + 6*a] -> sqrt), 
    sqrt][[1]] /. sqrt -> Sqrt[a^2 + 6*a]

(* {Sqrt[6 a + a^2] -> (a x - 3 α Subscript[C, 2])/x} *)

expr2 = expr /. rule1 /. rule2 // Simplify

(* (E^(I q y + (x + y) δ + ((7 I)/t + (5 I)/y) Subscript[C, 
   2]) Subscript[C, 1])/(4 E^((3 x + y) δ) + η) *)
```

Verifying,

```
expr == expr2 /. (Reverse /@ transforms) // Simplify

(* True *)
```